# Cardano-Wallet Killed

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to use cardano-wallet  https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/releases/tag/v2021-06-11
Still no success because it shows a message Killed whenever I try to execute any command.

My relay is 100% synced on test-net, I did the installation wget latest release for linux 64 *cardano-wallet-v2021-06-11-linux64.tar.gz*
extracted copy all files to */usr/local/bin* and so far so good, but when i try to execute cardano-wallet serve it shows killed and does nothing.

I'm running this node of version 1.27.0 on a docker container in a Mac M1 machine, I don't know if its relevant to say because its supposed that docker emulates a complete operational system.
Already did apt-get update and upgrade, no success.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to answer my question and I'll update the documentation of the project I'm creating about that.

First this setup won't work, macos M1 and running a test net node, unfortunately, wasn't compatible so I moved on to linux machine.

Comment: Could potentially be some incompatibility with the M1 chip, with such a new chip architecture. Check out https://doesitarm.com/app/haskell/